# Use Identity Server 4 as an Applications Portal

Tags: identityserver4

Good day everyone,

I am trying to create an Applications Landing portal using Identity Server 4 as my Token provider. I want the user to log into an application that lists their available applications (based on a list that I will get when that user logs in) and then allow the user to click on a button to go to that application.

*example: User clicks on Applications Landing page and logs in, they are then presented with a list of the web applications that they are allowed to access. They click on the button for the application that they would like to go to, and they are redirected to that application.*

Currently, all applications listed will be web apps (at the time of this writing) and I am stuck on how to tell the application (that the user clicks on) that the user is already authenticated. I don't want the user to have to log in a second time. This is similar to a SSO scenario.

I have already set up the Application Landing Portal app and the user can log into that app and get a list of the applications (clients) that are available to them.

But when an application is selected, the User identity is null (making them have to log in a second time).

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks,
Tim

Answer (score 0):

Send the user to a secured page of the *app*.

e.g.

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    [Authorize]
    public async IActionResult Login()
    {
    }
```

And on the Applications Landing page have a link like:

```
https://myapp.com/account/login
```

That will trigger authentication, redirecting the user back to the IdentityServer where the SSO cookie will take care of the automatic login and send an authenticated user back to the app.

Comment: Hey Ruard, I tried this from the second web app that I wanted to go to, and I all I got was a blank page that kept going back and forth between the ID4 server and the web app. It never ended. I eventually stopped it before it could crash my browser. 
So what I did was set the home controller of the second application (not the one that lists all the applications) so that it needed Authorization and when I clicked on the link to go to that application, it never went to it and I got nothing but a constant redirect.
Sigh... Any thoughts? Is there something special that I should be doing?

Comment: It seems that there is an issue with the redirect. Can you see what's in the logs? It looks like SSO works but the user isn't authenticated. There may be an error in the [order](https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-3.0#order) of the middleware or a problem with configuration.

Comment: Hey Ruard, I think I figured out why it was constantly redirecting, but I don't know how to fix it. It appears that my second app is a virual directory (IIS 10) to the apps portal page.
So Application Portal URL: https://appsPortal.test.com/
Second App URL: https://appsPortal.test.com/SecondApp
When I put the second app on it's own domain name (https://secondApp.test.com) the redirection works fine. Do you have any idea why? I thought that IS4 allowed subdomains. :( Thank you for the help that you have given me! I appreciate it.

Comment: `secondApp.test.com` is a subdomain so that confirms that IS4 allows subdomains. And `appsPortal.test.com/SecondApp` is not a subdomain, rather a subdirectory or an endpoint on the `appsPortal.test.com` domain.

Comment: I'm sorry, I misspoke. Still I don't know why IS4 keeps redirecting every time I go to that endpoint.

Comment: Since that's a different issue, not related to my answer, I suggest you ask a new question with details in order to solve the issue of redirecting first.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will ask another question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to build your solutions around [Skoruba IdentityServer 4 Admin](https://github.com/skoruba/IdentityServer4.Admin/) template. When a user logs in to admin center there is a section with Grants (applications authorized by the user). You can modify that section and add application icon and link there.

Comment: I looked at this and I am intrigued, I will have to install it next week and try it for admin of the ID4 server. Thanks for the link!

Comment: Let me know if you need help.